# Using a map with key-string with redundant information?

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary, stl, containers

I have a class `myClass`. A `myClass` object has a (human readable) name, and some more information.

```
class myClass
{
    std::string name;
    int attribute;
    int anotherAttribute;
}
```

They are stored inside a STL container, a `vector`, for example.

```
std::vector<myObject> myList;
```

When the client wants to access an element, it does this by name. That means, I have to iterate over the whole vector to find the correct object (the container contains about a few hundred objects).
So, I'm thinking of moving to `std::map` as container, instead of `vector`. As far as my understanding is, a map should be the container of choice when accessing elements by name, instead of an index.

However, then the name of the object is stored twice, once as the map key, and in the object itself. The memory overhead should be no problem, but I wonder if this is good practise. There may be the problem that the names run out of sync (for some mysterious reason). I even thought about dropping the `name` member of `myClass`.

To make it short: what container should I use, and why?

Comment: You could sort your `std::vector<myObject>` elements by name and use binary search, which by the way has the same time complexity in searching as `std::map`.

Comment: If you use C++11, you could use `std::unordered_map`, which is a hash map implementation. Then drop the `name` attribute from myClass as you'll always be able to get at it through the map anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You should choose your container based on the way your store and access data in it. So in your usecase you should definitely use a `unordered_map`

You should keep the `std::string` name attribute in your class if and only if you use it from inside the class.

So the question is will you at any point have to get the name from the object, rather than the object from its name.
This occurs when you get the object from the container and store it elsewhere, then use it later on.

Given the nature of `name` (which is most likely not going to change) you don't really have to worry about the `name` attribute not being "in sync" with the key you use in the `unordered_map`

If memory isn't a primary concern I'd advise you to keep it.